# Reading file and list/tuple iteration

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, iteration

I need to take the data from a file, remove the lines that begin with a comment hash, then read that file into a list. Then convert that list into a list tuples of start times, end times, and step count.

Here is the file: in form start_time, end_time, and step count (from FitBit data)

```
# read from file data about one day 
# format: start_time:end_time:#steps
09.30AM:09.45AM:220
11.45AM:12.23PM:300
11.45AM:10.23AM:302
2.45PM:3.23PM:202
3.45PM:3.53PM:90
5.45PM:5.53PM:80
6.45PM:7.23PM:1000
10.45PM:10.53PM:102
```

Here is the code I have so far which contains a function to read and split the data into a list of sublists, and then split it into tuples. **The problem that I cannot solve is to iterate through each start and end time and find MINUTES SINCE MIDNIGHT. and store them as ints** I cannot figure out how to iterate through the items in the sublists.

```
import sys

fname = sys.argv[1]

#Lines 26 - 34 reads file "in.dat",removes the comment lines,and stores each of the lines as a seperate tuple list in the form [str , str, str]
data = []
    with open("in.dat", "r") as f:
    for line in map(str.strip, f):
        if line == "" or line.startswith("#"):
            continue
        data.append(line.split(":"))
        data[-1][-1] = int(data[-1][-1])
    print(data)

def minutes_since_midnight(data):
    x = []
    for x in data:
        for y in x:
            y.split(".")
        print(x)**

minutes_since_midnight(data)

def convert_to_tuples(data):
    result = []
    for sublist in data:
        result.append(tuple(sublist))
    return result

result = convert_to_tuples(data)
```

So again my issues lies with how to convert the start times and end times in the "minutes_since_midnight" function to the minutes since midnight. Then store that data into tules using the following function.

I am super new to Python so any help will be greatly appreciated.

The expected outcome is a list like the following [(570, 585, 220 , ...]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the number of comments rows (or you can use your code to find that number), you can use `pandas` for this

```
import pandas as pd
# need to specify the seperator and skiprows
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=":", skiprows=2, header=None, names=['start', 'end', 'steps'])
```

output:

| start | end | steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09.30AM | 09.45AM | 220 |
| 11.45AM | 12.23PM | 300 |
| 11.45AM | 10.23AM | 302 |
| 2.45PM | 3.23PM | 202 |
| 3.45PM | 3.53PM | 90 |
| 5.45PM | 5.53PM | 80 |
| 6.45PM | 7.23PM | 1000 |
| 10.45PM | 10.53PM | 102 |

Then you can convert this into list if you need by using `df.to_list()`

Comment: Unfortunately I need to complete this with only the built-in python operations w/o using libraries or extensions

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen other posts about this, seems like you have been at it for a couple days.
test for "PM" in the value and after you split the `hours/mins` from the timestamp, adjust the hours.  multiply the `hours` x 60 and add the `mins` for total mins since midnight.

```py
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pp


in_dat = """\
# read from file data about one day 
# format: start_time:end_time:#steps
09.30AM:09.45AM:220
11.45AM:12.23PM:300
11.45AM:10.23AM:302
2.45PM:3.23PM:202
3.45PM:3.53PM:90
5.45PM:5.53PM:80
6.45PM:7.23PM:1000
10.45PM:10.53PM:102"""


def mins_since_midnight(arg):
    """ converts HH:MM to minutes by splitting on ':' and adding 12 hours if 'PM' in argument """
    meridiem = True if 'PM' in arg.upper() else False
    hours, mins = list(map(int, arg.strip('AMP').split(':')))
    if meridiem and hours < 12: hours += 12
    return hours * 60 + mins


# with open('in.dat', 'r') as file
with StringIO(in_dat) as file:
    results = []
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        start, stop, steps = line.strip().split(':')
        results.append((
            start.replace('.', ':'),
            stop.replace('.', ':'),
            int(steps)
        ))
pp(results)

converted_results = []
for start, stop, steps in results:
    converted_results.append((
        mins_since_midnight(start),
        mins_since_midnight(stop),
        steps
    ))
pp(converted_results)
```

output:

```
[('09:30AM', '09:45AM', 220),
 ('11:45AM', '12:23PM', 300),
 ('11:45AM', '10:23AM', 302),
 ('2:45PM', '3:23PM', 202),
 ('3:45PM', '3:53PM', 90),
 ('5:45PM', '5:53PM', 80),
 ('6:45PM', '7:23PM', 1000),
 ('10:45PM', '10:53PM', 102)]
[(570, 585, 220),
 (705, 743, 300),
 (705, 623, 302),
 (885, 923, 202),
 (945, 953, 90),
 (1065, 1073, 80),
 (1125, 1163, 1000),
 (1365, 1373, 102)]
```